# zoomplus magento - can't scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento, magiczoomplus

Ok so this is the site --> http://www.ascent.ro/bluza-rossignol-speedster-polo-ls-fw14.html

I've just added Magic Zoom Plus to a page and it's working as expected on desktop.

When I view this page on a mobile or Ipad, I can't scroll.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this scroll?

Comment: can you show me admin?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling the zoom on mobile? if not then add "data-mobile-options" to the parameter of your magiczoom. Also do check if your magiczoom is the latest version.

```
    <a class="MagicZoom" id="zoom" data-mobile-options="zoomMode: off" title="..." href="large-1.jpg"><img src="small-1.jpg"/></a>
```